# Place Polyline on top of everything

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, graph, plot, polyline

I'm working on my own plotting library, but i've run into a problem. I have the following code to put my polyline on the windowsphone page:

```
System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    graph.AddSinglePoint(x);
    graph.Update();
    LayoutRoot.UpdateLayout();
}); 

LayoutRoot.Children.Add(graph.line);
```

(its in a begin invoke, because i do this inside a timer_tick void which is called by a timer timeout(ms)

Only problem with this is, when i want to have my graph postioned lower on the form (in example y= 300 + the actual Y value). It pushes everything on my form down by 300. What I had in mind was the following:

> Layout: Page Title
>
> Some filling (listboxes, checkboxes, etc)
>
> At the bottom: My graph (polyline)

How do I acomplish something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a `Grid` for `LayoutRoot` you have to set the row and column of your graph:

```
   Grid.SetRow(graph,2);
   Grid.SetColumn(graph,...);
```

I personally would do it differently and use a separate control for my graph, eg a `Canvas`, so the layout looks like this:

```
Layout: Page Title
Some filling (listboxes, checkboxes, etc)
At the bottom: Canvas
```

then add the graph to the Canvas instead of the `LayoutRoot`. You can position controls in a `Canvas` by absolute coordinates via the dependency properties `Top` and `Left`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn about the [Silverlight Layout System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645025%28VS.95%29.aspx), the location of each element on screen is determined by the panel which it is located within. Some panels, such as `StackPanel`, 'stack' each of their children, so that no two items can overlap. Whereas others like `Grid` and `Canvas` permit an overlap.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply's. I have implemented the approach of pivotnig and that works fine..